# Good .rm/.rmvb to divx or xvid joiner/converter?

Tags: video, conversion

I used 'Total Video Converter' to convert and join some .rm/.rmvb files and it didn't work properly. Tried another one from Allok and it wasn't very reliable.

Any really good Real Video converters which can also join files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like PavTube.

Answer (score 1):

Two excellent video editors and joiners are [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) and [Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/).
If you don't have the required codec you can find them on [free-codecs.com](http://www.free-codecs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use free stuff. To do this in the past I used ffmpeg to convert the .rm files to AVI, then avidemux to handle the joining. Free Software both.